# Intercept and modify request body

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

In a request body object that I expect in my POST endpoint there are three fields, let's say A, B, C. Users can pass:
1. Both A and B 
2. Only C.

In the second case (when only C is provided) I need to retrieve A and B from mapping in a database and add these to the request body to be validated later in my custom authorization filter.

I've tried two thins - creating another authorization filter and delegate handler. I managed to get the A and B from a database, but I don't know how to add them to the request body. Also, once the request body stream was read it couldn't be used again in the validation function.

Comment: It'd help if you added some code to your post to make things a bit more concrete.

Comment: Instead of finding an answer to this problem, I'd recommend to re-think the design and save yourself from troubles down the line.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb and say that you shouldn't be looking to modify the incoming request.  Instead change the code in your 'custom authorization filter' to retrieve fields A and B when only C is provided.